# Notebook created from sharepoint is not reflected in graph api immediatly

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Onenote notebook created by navigating to `${site.webUrl}/_layouts/15/groupstatus.aspx?Target=NOTEBOOK` is not getting reflected in `GET /groups/{id}/onenote/notebooks` call

Notebook is available online at  `${site.webUrl}/_layouts/15/groupstatus.aspx?Target=NOTEBOOK` url

Status propagation takes seconds to hours to get notebook status in Graph API

Sometime Notebook is available sporadically i.e. it is available in one call but not in the next call. On further investigation server is different for pass/failed calls according to  `x-ms-ags-diagnostic` header